# Getting correct JSON format in API controller but double back slash in JSON where the result of api is used

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller

I am new to programming and specifically new to .Net MVC(using .net core 2). I am having a controller method as below

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetCountriesList(string searchText)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
        string responseContent = string.Empty;

        List<Country> listCountries = null;
        using (var client = getHttpClient(WebClientContentType.JSON))
        {
            responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}", _webApiUrl, "/api/Country/GetCountryList")));
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseContent = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                listCountries =(List<Country>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent, typeof(List<Country>));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
                {
                    listCountries = listCountries.Where(m => m.ShortName.ToLower().StartsWith(searchText.ToLower())).ToList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(responseMessage.StatusCode);
            }


        }

        return Json(listCountries);
    }
```

Here in "responseContent", i am getting extra slashes in my JSON

But in the API method, i am getting properly formatted JSON string
My API method is

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Country/GetCountryList")]
    public IActionResult GetCountryList()
    {
        ProcedureReturnType mediaType = GetMediaType();

        try
        {
            CountryHelper countryHelper = new CountryHelper();
            var result = countryHelper.GetCountries(mediaType);

            return Ok(result);
        } // end try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        } // end catch

    } // end method
```

Any way, i can solve this issue as i need the list of countries which i expect to get from the valid JSON in listCountries

For example if i write

```
 var result = "\r";

            return Ok(result);
```

Then the result sent is "\r", but on the receiving end at line

responseContent is having the value "\"\r\""

Comment: Post the output of each layer

Comment: responseContent is C# string and in C# double quotes are represented as \" so I think thats why you are seeing extra slashes. As far as the json is correctly deserializing into List<Country> the json returned by your API is perfectly valid

Comment: I have updated the output

Comment: @MohsinMehmood. I don't know but while debugging when i am through the deserialization line, nothing happens, no exception, no output as if continue is clicked. But i am not able to get my list of countries in UI. With webClient i am able to achieve the same using, client.DownloadString(Uri). But i am supposed to use aync and HttpClient